# How to select on junction table depending on student ID

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, database, vb.net

first sorry my english is bad.

I am having a problem using junction table it only return me 1 subject this is my query.

I have a 
**Student_tbl**, **Subject_tbl** , **student_subject_tbl** the junction table.

And this is my query i am using vb.net

```
SELECT subject_name 
FROM student_subject 
     JOIN student ON student.StudentID = student_subject.student_id 
     JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id 
WHERE student.StudentID='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

What i want to do is i just want to select all **subject name** that is belong to the **student_id**  student id is equals to my textbox in vb.net that is where i will type the student id of student. THank you so much.

EDIT:
I am trying to display the value of all subject name of the entered student id on the textbox. this is my vb.code on displaying it only display the first subject on **subject_tbl**

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = dr(0)
            'Label4.Text = dr(1)
            TextBox4.Text = dr(1)
            TextBox5.Text = dr(2)
            TextBox6.Text = dr(3)
            TextBox7.Text = dr(4)
            TextBox8.Text = dr(5)
            dr.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to Join with Students table, since the Id's are stored in the junction table also and you are not retrieving student information, also use parameterized command instead of building the command manually **to avoid SQL injection**.

Try using the following code:

```
Dim strQuery as string = "SELECT subject_name " & _
" FROM student_subject " & _
" INNER JOIN subject_bsit ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id" & _
" WHERE student_subject.student_id = @StudentID"

Dim cmd as New MySqlCommand(strQuery,connection)

cmd.AddParameterWithValue("@StudentID",Textbox1.text)

cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

## Update 1

The index you pass to the datareader object is the column index not the row index, also you have to use a loop instead of an if condition:

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While dr.Read = True Then

    Msgbox(dr(0).Tostring())

End While
dr.Close()
```

## Update 2 - passing textboxes name dynamically

First, you have to make sure that the number of textboxes is less than or equal to the number of rows returned.

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim cnt as Integer = 1

While dr.Read = True Then

    Dim txt As New TextBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(string.Format("Textbox{0}", cnt ),false).FirstOrDefault(),Textbox);

    txt.Text = dr(0).ToString()

    cnt += 1

End While
dr.Close()
```

**But Why not showing results in a GridView??**

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer now i have a different error it say "index was outside of array"

cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read = True Then
            TextBox2.Text = dr(0)
            'Label4.Text = dr(1)
            TextBox4.Text = dr(1)
            TextBox5.Text = dr(2)
            TextBox6.Text = dr(3)
            TextBox7.Text = dr(4)
            TextBox8.Text = dr(5)
            dr.Close()

I want to display all o the subject on each textbox.

Comment: @Kimberypalet you are only selecting `subject_name ` the nyou cannot use indexes higher than `0` >> `dr(0)` is only acceptable others will throw an exception

Comment: @Kimberypalet if you need more columns then add the to the SELECT query

Comment: Hi, sorry i tried diffrent query for almost 2 days and didn't fix it.  The student_id can have many subject . Example the ID=1 that id 1 have many subject on it exact is there are 8 subject or id 1.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your apply your update.

Comment: @Kimberypalet also feel free to read the [Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about the site rules *(asking good questions and answers, accepting answers ...)*

Comment: Thank you so much. It works can i ask one last question if it is ok if not i will try to search more again. Thanks. 
.
I just want to ask if how can i pass it on the textbox i tried  this code and it gave me out o boud index o array again. But for your code on message box it is working properly. THank you.
While dr.Read = True

            TextBox2.Text = (dr(0).ToString())
            TextBox4.Text = (dr(1).ToString())
            TextBox5.Text = (dr(2).ToString())
        End While

Comment: @Kimberypalet why showing result in textboxes not a datagrid

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply.  i get an error txt is not a method on txt>text
.
Actually i am trying to make a chart like design where i can display it on a textbox from first year to fourth year right now i am trying to output a student subject first year class first sem on the textbox sorry i am trying hard to explain.

Comment: @Kimberypalet fixed it it was a writing mistake

Comment: @Kimberypalet If the answers solves the issue don't forget to accept it, also feel free to upvote if you found it helpful

Comment: I get this error on "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "
txt.Text = dr(0).ToString()

I just need to click the Check button right ?? Thanks.

Comment: @Kimberypalet try it now

Comment: I  just tried it now sir. It gave me an error  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " txt.Text = dr(0).ToString()

Comment: I mentioned in my question that `First, you have to make sure that the number of textboxes is less than or equal to the number of rows returned.`, the error is thrown because the number of textboxes is less than the rows returned